# DataGridView DataGridViewComboBoxCell value does not change

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have this datagridview that some of the row's cells might be a combobox.
I can bind the combobox and it initializes correctly, yet when I select an item from that combobox, the Value property of the control remains the same yet the formatted value is changed to the new selected item.

Here is how I load the combobox into my grid view:

```
private void ADDComboBoxItemToView(string itemName, Languages.LanguagesEnum language = Languages.LanguagesEnum.English)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell c = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
    c.DataSource = LanguagesManager.LanguageNames.GetLanguages();
    c.ValueType = typeof(Languages.LanguagesEnum);
    c.Value = language;
    c.ValueMember = "LangID";
    c.DisplayMember = "LangName";
    c.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;


    var id = dgItems.Rows.Add(new object[] { filePath });
    dgItems.Rows[id].Cells[1] = c;
}
```

And this is my data source class:

```
public class LanguageNames
{
    public Languages.LanguagesEnum LangID { get; set; }

    public int LangNum
    {
        get { return (int) LangID; }
    }

    public string LangName
    {
        get { return GetLanguageName(LangID); }
    }

    private string GetLanguageName(Languages.LanguagesEnum id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
            case Languages.LanguagesEnum.English:
                return "English";
            case Languages.LanguagesEnum.Finnish:
                return "Finnish";
            case Languages.LanguagesEnum.French:
                return "French";
            default:
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public static List<LanguageNames> GetLanguages()
    {
        return _languages;
    }

    private static readonly List<LanguageNames> _languages = new List<LanguageNames>
    {
            new LanguageNames{LangID = Languages.LanguagesEnum.English},
            new LanguageNames{LangID = Languages.LanguagesEnum.Finnish},
            new LanguageNames{LangID = Languages.LanguagesEnum.French}
    };
}
```

And this is how I handle the selection change event:

```
private void dgItems_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgItems.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.Control is ComboBox)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
        comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += LastColumnComboSelectionChanged;
    }
}

private void LastColumnComboSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentcell = dgItems.CurrentCellAddress;
    DataGridViewTextBoxCell celItem = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)dgItems.Rows[currentcell.Y].Cells[0];
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell celLang = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgItems.Rows[currentcell.Y].Cells[1];

    var item = celItem.Value.ToString();
    var language = (Languages.LanguagesEnum) celLang.Value;

    _IsSaveRequired = true;
}
```

The problem here is `celLang.Value` always returns `English` no matter how many times I change between the languages in the combobox. Yet if I call `celLang.FormattedValue` I get the correct language string.

I really need the language value as an Enum and cannot benefit from the FormattedValue.

If I do not initialize the combobox, remove `c.Value = language;` line, I get an "object reference" exception at `var language = (Languages.LanguagesEnum) celLang.Value;` and `celLang.Value` is null;

Can someone help pls?

EDIT:

this the languages enumerator:

```
public enum LanguagesEnum
{
    English,
    Finnish,
    French
}
```

Comment: `LastColumnComboSelectionChanged` seems like a road to nowhere.  `item` and `language` are local variables that aren't used after instantiating.  I may be reading it wrong.

Comment: @FelixCastor I would have added some code to reflect the change in `language` but the problem is `celLang.Value` always returns the same value (the one it was initialized with)

Comment: Is `LastColumnComboSelectionChanged` ever called when you change the combo??

Comment: @TaW yes it gets called. But the value never changes only the formatted value does.

Comment: What is wrong with just using FormattedValue?  If that is giving you the value you want after a comboBox change then why can't you just use that?  Convert the FormattedValue back to the enum you've established if you have to.

Comment: Ah. Maybe adding an dgItems.EndEdit in the LastColumnComboSelectionChanged code will help then?

Comment: @jaredbaszler the formattedValue will be the name of each language in its own language. I have only posted a sample of the languages here, the end product will have 30+ languages each displayed in its own language using japanese, chinese, korean, hebrew and many other characters that cannot be casted to the enum.

Comment: @TaW that did not work I'm afraid. As I said the value property is stuck with its initial value, no matter how many times you change selection it will remain the same.

Comment: Honestly if nothing works, I am thinking of enumerating the languages list and comparing the FormattedValue against each entry in the list and returning the enum value on a match. But I am not dropping the towel yet.

Answer (score 0):

If someone has same problem, try to change `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DisplayStyle` to `ComboBox`. Default is `DropDownButton`. I had same issue and after this change everything works properly.